# Writing hex digest to file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a bot that makes a request to open a page and obtain image links and downloads them. However, I noticed that when I tried to download the image to my current working directory, I receive an empty image file. I've provided a scenario below.

**Edit:**

I realized that what was causing this is checking to see if the image count is equal to the max. For some reason it's not performing the final write process when making the request causing it to write a blank image. How can I resolve this?

**Code Scenario:**

```
var request = require('request');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');

var md5 = function (pic) {
  var hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
  hash.update(pic);
  return hash.digest('hex');
};

var pics = ['http://37.media.tumblr.com/eea272630e7c0749241b1594b1b911b4/tumblr_n1t63oOzF81rt268so1_1280.jpg',
           'http://38.media.tumblr.com/9b40422b9129745292b174ffd683e8f3/tumblr_mvhhcuOQn41rt268so1_1280.jpg',    
           'http://37.media.tumblr.com/7f96f676610efa9beb2f322c4f6eeb36/tumblr_mudrsmtKtl1r4lu5ao1_1280.jpg'
];

var downloadCount = 0, max = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
  var hexDigest = md5(pics[i]) + pics[i].slice(-4);
  request(pics[i]).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(process.cwd() + '/' + hexDigest));
  downloadCount++;
  if (downloadCount === max) {
    process.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me, assuming `pics` is an array of urls such as the one you posted.

Comment: Strange, I keep getting empty images. I've been trying to crack this for a while. I've added a test array just to add more context to the problem. @PatrikOldsberg

Comment: I tried the links you posted. Everything is working and I'm feeling slightly more hungry.

Comment: Haha, not a problem. I might have duplicates lying around which might be causing this. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I edited the post. This is what was causing the problem. @PatrikOldsberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're looping through the array of images and doing the requests, you're creating asynchronous streams. The following line of code only starts the download, it does not wait for the download to complete:

```
request(pics[i]).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(process.cwd() + '/' + hexDigest));
```

When you're checking the download count and exiting the process once it has reached max, the downloads are interrupted before they have even gotten the chance to start.

A possible solution is to move the download counter to an `end` event listener on the stream, like so:

```
request(pics[i]).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(process.cwd() + '/' + hexDigest))
  .on('end', function () {
    downloadCount++;
    if (downloadCount === max) {
      process.exit(0);
    }
  });
```

It can also be solved using a library such as [async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Also, the NodeJS runtime keeps track of the number of callbacks (= streams) that are active, an will exit the process once they are all completed. So unless something else is forcing you to stop the program with `process.exit` you don't need to track the download count at all.

Comment: Very helpful, I owe you one. I learned a lot from this writing this and I hope this helps out others as much as this has.

Comment: I'm still trying to get my hear around this, it's still ignoring the count and I can't console log during where the count is being incremented.

Comment: Have you removed the semicolon at the end of the first line?

Comment: Yeah, of course! I'm thinking this is best to handle with async. That's taken me some time to understand, especially when I've never had to handle things like this.